# How to use magicyuv & utvideo codec with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to know how to use [magicyuv](https://www.magicyuv.com/) & utvideo codec with ffmpeg

Comment: Answer edited (see below) It depends on the version you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Linux command searches all `codecs` than can `E`ncode anything containing `ut`.

```
  ffmpeg -codecs | grep --regexp="^ .E" | grep --ignore-case ut
```

and its output is:

```
 DEVI.S utvideo              Ut Video
```

so you can use:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Videos/WebCam/me.mp4 -c:v utvideo -r 30 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 512K /tmp/test.mkv
```

#### However:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep --regexp="^ .E" | grep --ignore-case magic
```

has no output at all ***on my version of ffmpeg***, but if your version supports it, you *will see an output* and then you just use whatever is in the second column as per the example above for `utvideo`.

Comment: Check your ffmpeg version. MagicYUV encoder has been present since 4.0

Comment: And to list only encoders, you can run `ffmpeg -encoders`

Comment: @Gyan Answer edited to include your comment as I have the standard version that came with my distro and it does what it needs to do, so not adding (yet another) PPA.  **P.S.** you have enough rep to [edit] my answer.  **0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby No need for a PPA since [recent ffmpeg builds can just be downloaded](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Users often get mad when their answers are edited: comments are less intrusive.

Comment: @llogan yeah, but then you need to download and install manually.  That's why I just stay with the standard...